# Need help with LATEX table multirow multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, overleaf

```
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ref &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Manufacturers} &
  Model &
  DC Motor(Brushed) &
  AC Induction Motor &
  PM Brushed DC Motor &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}PM-Sync Reluctance \\ Motor(PM-SynRM)\end{tabular}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Permanent Magnet Synchronous \\ Motor(PMSM)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Toyota}} & Toyota Prius &  &  &\\ 
    \hhline{~~----}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} Toyota RAV4 &  &  & \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Tesla}} & Model S &  &  &\\
    \hhline{~~----}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} Model X &  &  & \\
    \hhline{~~----}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} Model 3 &  &  & \\
    \hhline{~~----}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} Model Y &  &  & \\ \hline
 & Nissan         &Nissan Leaf  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 & Porsche        &Porsche Taycon  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 & Audi           &Audi e-tron  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{BMW}} & BMW i3 &  &  &\\ 
    \hhline{~~----}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} BMW-Mini E &  &  & \\ \hline
 & General Motors &GM EV1  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 & Fiat Panda     &Fiat Panda Elettra  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{KIA}} & Soul EV &  &  &\\ 
    \hhline{~~----}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} Niro EV &  &  & \\ \hline
 & Ather Energy   &Ather 450X  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

[image: This is the ouput i am getting][image: This is the acutual table that i want]

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Maybe you could explain where the problem is...?

Comment: Actually, 1st image is the output that I'm getting by the above code and also the full table is not showing in the document. 2nd image is the table that I want. Kindly help me with this

Comment: Oh I see, the table is overflowing in your IEEE document. Kindly consider modifiying your code and adding a MWE, so other users can compile it and experiment with it. Please check [What is an MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). On a first glance, the overflowing of the table comes from `resizebox{\textwidth}`. Maybe it's not considering that is a two column document?

Comment: Also, maybe it's because it's not working properly, but there seems to be some cells merging where they should be separated. In the case that you are not very experienced with tables, may I suggest an [online latex table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/)?

Comment: Your table appears to be quite wide, so I assume it won't fit into one column of text that easily. Could you introduce some kind of abbreviation in the column headers of columns 4 to 6 as well?

Comment: yes the doc is two-column document, and I think that's the only reason it's not considering resizebox{\textwidth}

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alternative approaches:

[image]

PErsonally, I'd suggest using a table with no vertical and less horizontal lines, such as the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ref &
  \thead{Manufacturers} &
  \thead{Model} &
  \thead{DC Motor\\ (Brushed)} &
  \thead{AC Induction\\ Motor} &
  \thead{PM Brushed\\ DC Motor} &
  \thead{PM-Sync Reluctance \\ Motor(PM-SynRM)} &
  \thead{Permanent Magnet\\ Synchronous  Motor(PMSM)} \\ \hline
  & \multirow{2}{*}{Toyota} & Toyota Prius        &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Toyota RAV4         &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & \multirow{4}{*}{Tesla}  & Model S             &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Model X             &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Model 3             &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Model Y             &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Nissan                  & Nissan Leaf         &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Porsche                 & Porsche Taycon      &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Audi                    & Audi e-tron         &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & \multirow{2}{*}{BMW}    & BMW i3              &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & BMW-Mini E          &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & General Motors          & GM EV1              &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Fiat Panda              & Fiat Panda Elettra  &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & \multirow{2}{*}{KIA}    & Soul EV             &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Niro EV             &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Ather Energy            & Ather 450X          &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\lipsum

\begin{table}
\scriptsize
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\scriptsize}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont DC Motor (Brushed)}
\begin{tabular}{|c|m{\widthof{General}}|m{\widthof{Model X}}|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ref &
  \thead{Manu-\\facturers} &
  \thead{Model} &
  \rothead{DC Motor (Brushed)} &
  \rothead{AC Induction Motor} &
  \rothead{PM Brushed DC Motor} &
  \rothead{PM-Sync Reluctance  Motor (PM-SynRM)} &
  \rothead{Permanent Magnet Synchronous  Motor (PMSM)} \\ \hline
  & \multirow{3}{*}{Toyota} & Toyota Prius        &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Toyota RAV4         &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & \multirow{4}{*}{Tesla}  & Model S             &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Model X             &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Model 3             &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Model Y             &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Nissan                  & Nissan Leaf         &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Porsche                 & Porsche Taycon      &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Audi                    & Audi\newline e-tron         &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & \multirow{4}{*}{BMW}    & BMW i3              &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & BMW-Mini E          &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & General Motors          & GM EV1              &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Fiat Panda              & Fiat Panda Elettra  &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & \multirow{2}{*}{KIA}    & Soul EV             &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{3-8}
  &                         & Niro EV             &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
  & Ather Energy            & Ather 450X          &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont PM-SynRM}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} c l l c c c c c @{}}
\toprule
Ref &
  \thead{Manufacturers} &
  \thead{Model} &
  \rothead{DCM} &
  \rothead{ACIndM} &
  \rothead{PMBDCM} &
  \rothead{PM-SynRM} &
  \rothead{PMSM} \\ 
  \midrule
  & Toyota         & Toyota Prius        &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  &                & Toyota RAV4         &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  & Tesla          & Model S             &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  &                & Model X             &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  &                & Model 3             &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  &                & Model Y             &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  & Nissan         & Nissan Leaf         &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  & Porsche        & Porsche Taycon      &  &  &  &  & \\
  \addlinespace 
  & Audi           & Audi e-tron         &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  & BMW            & BMW i3              &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  &                & BMW-Mini E          &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  & General Motors & GM EV1              &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  & Fiat Panda     & Fiat Panda Elettra  &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \addlinespace
  & KIA            & Soul EV             &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  &                & Niro EV             &  &  &  &  & \\
  \addlinespace
  & Ather Energy   & Ather 450X          &  &  &  &  & \\ 
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{8}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{DCM:~DC Motor (Brushed); ACIndM:~AC Induction Motor; PMBDCM:~PM Brushed DC Motor; PM-SynRM:~PM-Sync Reluctance  Motor; PMSM:~Permanent Magnet Synchronous  Motor} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\lipsum


\EOD
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me with this. Its really helpful and i got my desired result

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that does *not* use `\scalebox` or `\resizebox`, employs a landscape format layout, a `tabularx` environment to allow automatic line-breaking in the final four columns, dispenses with all vertical rules and most horizontal rules, and simplifies the entries in column 3, "Model". For instance, "Prius" and "RAV4" is just as informative, and less repetitious, as "Toyota Prius" and "Toyota RAV4".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e,rotating,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lll *{5}{>{\RaggedRight}X} @{}}
\toprule
  Ref &
  Manufacturer &
  Model &
  DC Motor (Brushed) &
  AC Induction Motor &
  PM Brushed DC Motor &
  PM-Sync Reluctance Motor \mbox{(PM-SynRM)} &
  Permanent Magnet Synchronous Motor (PMSM)\\ 
\midrule
  & Toyota & Prius   &  &  & \\ 
  &        & RAV4    &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
  & Tesla  & Model S &  &  & \\
  &        & Model X &  &  & \\
  &        & Model 3 &  &  & \\
  &        & Model Y &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
  & Nissan & Leaf    &  &  &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
  & Porsche& Taycon  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
  & Audi   & e-tron  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
  & BMW    & i3      &  &  & \\ 
  &        & Mini E  &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
  & GM     & EV1     &  &  &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
  & Fiat   & Panda Elettra  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
  & KIA    & Soul EV &  &  & \\ 
  &        & Niro EV &  &  & \\ \addlinespace
  & Ather Energy & 450X  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ Jes suggested, the latex table generator will do the job

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
                \hline
                Ref &
                Manufactures &
                Models &
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}DC\\ Motor\\ (Brushed)\end{tabular} &
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}AC\\ Induction\\ Motor\end{tabular} &
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}DC\\ (Brushless)\\ Motor\end{tabular} &
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PM-Sync\\ Reluctance\\ Motor\\ (PMSyncRM)\end{tabular} &
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Permanent\\ Magnet-Sync.\\ Motor (PMSM)\end{tabular} \\ \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{Toyota}                                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Toyota\\ Primus\end{tabular}      &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{3-8} 
                &                                                          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Toyota\\ RAV4\end{tabular}        &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                \multirow{4}{*}{} & \multirow{4}{*}{TESLA}                                   & Model S                                                      &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{3-8} 
                &                                                          & Model X                                                      &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{3-8} 
                &                                                          & Model 3                                                      &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{3-8} 
                &                                                          & Model Y                                                      &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                & Nissan                                                   & Nissan Leaf                                                  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                & Porsche                                                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Porsche\\ Taycan\end{tabular}     &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                & Audi                                                     & Audi e-tron                                                  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{BMW}                                     & BMW i3                                                       &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{3-8} 
                &                                                          & BMW-Mini E                                                   &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}General\\ Motors\end{tabular} & GM EV1                                                       &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                & Fiat Panda                                               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Fiat Panda\\ Elettra\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{KIA}                                     & Soul EV                                                      &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{3-8} 
                &                                                          & Nitro EV                                                     &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                & Ather Energy                                             & Ather 450X                                                   &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}%
        }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you soo much, it's really helpful and I get this one. Once again thank you

Comment: Using `\resizebox` in order to make a table fit into a given space will inevitably lead to inconsistent font sizez, something you might want to avoid.

Comment: @leandriis Is `scalebox` an option or change the format to `landscape`?

Comment: `scalebox` also leads to inconsistent font sized and so does `adjustbox`. For some alternative approaches that don't involve scaling tables, you might ant to take a look at [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for the additional input